# Why will my Kendo chart for angular render mock data but not real data?

Tags: angular, charts, kendo-ui

I'm trying to render a graph with Kendo Charts for Angular, and it is not working.

First, I tried it with mock data and it worked:

[image]

Here is my code:

```
<kendo-chart>
    <kendo-chart-series>
      <kendo-chart-title text="Large Data"></kendo-chart-title>
      <kendo-chart-series-item
        type="scatterLine"
        [style]="'smooth'"
        [data]="largeData"
        yField="value"
        xField="date"
      >
      </kendo-chart-series-item>
    </kendo-chart-series>
    <kendo-chart-x-axis>
        <kendo-chart-x-axis-item [labels]="{ format: 'MMM d, yy - hh:mm:ss a', rotation: 'auto' }">
        </kendo-chart-x-axis-item>
    </kendo-chart-x-axis>
  </kendo-chart>
```

and...

```
    const startDate = new Date('1/1/2019');
    for (let i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
      const date = new Date(JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(startDate)));
      date.setDate(startDate.getDate() + i);
      const value = Math.random() * 100;
      this.largeData.push({
        date,
        value
      });
    }
```

Since I got that working, I tried the next step of grabbing actual data from the backend like this:

```
    this.readingClient
      .query(filter, orderBy, skip, top, select)
      .pipe(retry(1))
      .subscribe((response) => {
        response.data.forEach(d => {
          this.largeData.push({
            date: d.readingDate,
            value: d.readingValues?.aCMitigationAmps?.value
          });
        });
      });
```

...but it doesn't render:

[image]

Here is a sample of the data in largeData that comes back from the backend:

[image]

I think there's something wrong with the dates. Note that the date axis is 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1 ... even though I told it to format the dates as `'MMM d, yy - hh:mm:ss a'`. Also, if I remove the formatting and add `[baseUnit]="days"` I get 0, 0.2, 0.4, 0.6 ... all the way up to 1.2, which is exactly the values along the y-axis (as if it's using the same values for both axis).

Can anyone see what I'm doing wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As [Documentation](https://www.telerik.com/kendo-angular-ui/components/charts/chart/data-binding/#toc-replacing-the-array-instance) suggests

> To trigger the change detection, create a new array instance for the collection—for example, instead of the this.data.push({new item}) array, set a this.data = [...this.data, {new item}] one.

Which basically means you need to reassign your `largeData` with a new array which you return from a backend. Maybe try:

```
this.readingClient
  .query(filter, orderBy, skip, top, select)
  .pipe(retry(1))
  .subscribe((response) => {
    response.data.forEach(d => {
      const backendData = [];
      backendData.push({
        date: d.readingDate,
        value: d.readingValues?.aCMitigationAmps?.value
      });
      this.largeData = backendData
    });
  });
```

Comment: Thanks Beka, that worked. But just for my understanding, why would I have to reset the largeData array in the case of pulling the data from the backend, but not in the case of generating mock data on the frontend? In both cases, the largeData array begins empty and then gets populated one record at a time. The graph shouldn't care where the data comes from.

Comment: I have to guess but you might've had that starting code in a onInit hook. basically what was happening is that mock data was created before your component was ready to deploy kendo graph to a screen (HTML wise), hence it is already there.- as for the backend, data is late for component initialization and has to be re-rendered. checkout [lifecycle hooks](https://angular.io/guide/lifecycle-hooks) for further instructions.

Comment: Yes, that sounds like what was happening. Again, thanks